# How can I create a big matrix without Memory Error?

Tags: python, matrix, memory, out-of-memory, html-parsing

I am analyzing a collection of HTML webpages in Python, to do that I'm dividing that webpages into several blocks, then I need to calculate the similarity between that blocks generating one feature vector for each block and then I compare all the vectors

However, I need to save the result of all similarities calculated so I need a matrix with size totalBlocks x totalBlocks.

After analyzing my program, I saw that I have around `35.000` blocks so it's a very large matrix `(35000x35000)` and then I am having a Memory Error when I am creating this matrix.

Here is the function where I create the matrix:

```
#Function to inicialize a matrix with number of rows and columns.
def inicializeMatrix(nColumns, nRows, value):
    return [[value for i in range(nColumns)] for j in range(nRows)]
```

And here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\contentExtractorAlgorithm.py", line 329, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\contentExtractorAlgorithm.py", line 298, in main
    wordsDict, totalBlocks, nPages = contentExtractor(datasetFolder, tagSet, destFolder)                
  File ".\contentExtractorAlgorithm.py", line 234, in contentExtractor
    similarityMatrix = inicializeMatrix(totalBlocks, totalBlocks, -1)
  File ".\contentExtractorAlgorithm.py", line 110, in inicializeMatrix
    return [ [ value for i in range(nColumns) ] for j in range(nRows) ]
  File ".\contentExtractorAlgorithm.py", line 110, in <listcomp>
    return [ [ value for i in range(nColumns) ] for j in range(nRows) ]
  File ".\contentExtractorAlgorithm.py", line 110, in <listcomp>
    return [ [ value for i in range(nColumns) ] for j in range(nRows) ]
MemoryError
```

So how can I solve this problem? Any help? Thank you so much.

Comment: That list comprehension is going to build the entire thing in memory, which you obviously don't want. Write a generator function and minimize the amount in memory at one time.

Comment: ...or buy and install more RAM.